# Magento Newsletter Subscription

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i set allow subscribed guest as an yes but when i add any guest email id then it will display like this, "There was a problem with the subscription" in newsletter in magento

Comment: he error will be shown only if the subscriber has an account in magento store and he is not logged in.If the subscriber is a guest customer then the error will not be shown,

Comment: @MagikVishal : It is not like that, this problem is still available.

Comment: @MagikVishal : i also change SubscriberController.php file for Newsletter Validation but still it is not working.